# Quadcopter beginner using pigpio

Tags: pwm, pigpio

I'm trying to build quadcopter using my raspberry pi. I have a few questions I would like to get some answers..

1. When I connect my ESC to the battery is starts beeping with 1-2 seconds spaces and never stops. What does that mean? (I bought the ESC from here: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4set-lot-Universal-RC-Quadcopter-Part-Kit-1045-Propeller-1pair-30A-Brushless-ESC-A2212-1000KV-Outrunner/32594550829.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.fd4hOU)
2. I'm using pigpio library to control PWM pulses. I connect the ESC to the raspberry in GPIO17 (pin 11). I tried using this commence sequence: [How to initialize an ESC with Python code](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29551/how-to-initialize-an-esc-with-python-code) with no luck..

The ESC has three cables: brown, red and orange. I connected the brown to GND, the red to 5V and the orange to GPIO17 (Pin 11).
The ESC is connected to a LIPO battery of 3500mAh, 11.1V

Any help will be much appreciated, I'm no looking for code but only for some directions..

Comment: As a minimum we need a clear photo of the connections between the Pi and the ESC.

Comment: @joan I added description of the connections. Thansk

Comment: for what us bad luck exactly

Comment: as for the beep, I think it is caused by 2, the ESC is not receiving zero then full throttle. solving problem 2 will solve both