# ESC control by Raspberry Pi B to manage brushless motors via Python

Tags: gpio, python, pwm

This post may be similar to other ones, but they didn't solve my problem: I've got four Hobbywing Skywalker 40 A [electronic speed controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speed_control) (ESC), to control four brushless motors ([these ones](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__18968__Turnigy_D2836_9_950KV_Brushless_Outrunner_Motor.html)) to make a quadcopter. I plugged a [LiPo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) 3S 3000 mAh 10C battery to the ESC, then the motor to the ESC, and finally the Raspberry Pi to the ESC, without the 5 V 3 A [battery eliminator circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_eliminator_circuit) (BEC).

Here is what it looks like [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVO77.jpg).

I know the Raspberry Pi isn't powered, it's just to show ;)
And then... I have no idea what to do.

There's a nice melody comming from the ESC when I plug it, and then "beep"s every two seconds, and the motor nods!

I know that an ESC is controlled by a [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) signal just like a servo, but I'm new to Python, and I haven't deal with servos before.

Comment: Which posts didn't solve your problem and what have you tried?

Comment: What I saw on other posts is that I need to calibrate my ESCs, but I have no idea how to do that... [link](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-control-a-traxxas-xl-5-esc-directly-from-the-gpio?rq=1) This post talk about buttons and led on the ESC, but mine don't have one. Moreover, he says that I need [that](http://www.adafruit.com/products/815) kind of card, but on [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=44800) says I don't need them (sorry it's french).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi can provide accurate servo signals on all the GPIOs without the need to buy additional hardware. There is an awful lot of out-of-date information on the web. Nobody has time to trawl through and correct all the misinformation on the web.

I suggest my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) or servoblaster as the best choice for the Raspberry Pi.

I suggest you [download, make, and install pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html) and try a quick experiment.

---

```
sudo pigpiod # Start the pigpio daemon

pigs servo **esc** 2000 mils 2000 servo **esc** 1000 mils 2000 # Arm the ESC

pigs servo **esc** 1200 # Open throttle slightly
```

where **esc** is the (Broadcom) number of a GPIO you have connected to an ESC control wire.

---

pigs is the name of a utility which sends commands to the pigpio daemon.

servo **g** **pw** starts servo pulses with width **pw** on (Broadcom) GPIO **g**.

mils **ms** pauses for **ms** milliseconds.

man pigs # For fuller information